# namespace StripeCustomerUpdateSubscriptionOptions can not be found

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I'm updating from stripe.net 1.2.0 dll

My original code was this
    var myUpdatedSubscription = new StripeCustomerUpdateSubscriptionOptions();
but now I get no namespace not found error
with the new stripe.net v7.

```
var myUpdatedSubscription = new StripeCustomerUpdateSubscriptionOptions();
                        myUpdatedSubscription.PlanId = SelectedSubscription;
                        myUpdatedSubscription.TokenId = stripeToken;
                        myUpdatedSubscription.Quantity = 1;

                        var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
                        StripeSubscription subscription = customerService.UpdateSubscription(StripeCustomerID, myUpdatedSubscription);

                        objCompany.SubscribeCompany(CompanyID, StripeCustomerID, SelectedSubscription);
                        pnlForm.Visible = false;
                        pnlPaymentSuccessful.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You'll want to read the documentation which explains how you update an existing subscription now: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#updating-a-subscription or create one https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#creating-a-subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing subscriptions has moved from the `StripeCustomerService` to the new `StripeSubscriptionService`. With this, the name of some of the types involved has changed, too. So, for example, instead of `StripeCustomerUpdateSubscriptionOptions`, you do now use `StripeSubscriptionUpdateOptions`.

Comment: thanks!   do u know where CurrentPeriodStart went? it seems it should be under subscriptions but it's not. var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
         StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Get(StripeCustomerID);
        string CustomerDescription = stripeCustomer.Description.ToString();
         DateTime SubscriptionStarts = (DateTime)stripeCustomer.Subscription.CurrentPeriodStart;

Comment: @user713813 You now get the subscription from the StripeSubscriptionService using the Get method passing the customerId and subscriptionId. Just use the documentation on github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net to find out how to do what.

Comment: in case anyone is curious you use   var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService(); IEnumerable<StripeSubscription> responses = subscriptionService.List(stripeCustomer.Id.ToString()); and then   
                        foreach( var response in responses )
                        {
                            StripeSubscriptionID = response.Id.ToString();
                        }

Comment: is there a way to get the StripeInvoiceItems by invoiceid?

Comment: Note that in the latest releases of Stripe that the word 'Stripe' has been dropped from most, if not possibly all, class names. So StripeCustomerService is now CustomerService e.t.c.

Comment: The documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=dotnet included the updated class names.